# How google (and other SEs) find pages for web crawlers to index?

Tags: search, web-crawler, search-engine

When you build a web crawler, you define a page url and it runs through this page and all the links on this page, etc..
But what is indexed by search engines? I mean, they cant just print World Wide Web in the url and all of the sites will be crawled...
So basically what are they crawling?

And I also wanted to know, if I crawl a website, can it be considered as DOS attack?
I mean no harm and I just want to collect the information. So should I be worried about being blamed as a person, who launches Denial Of Service attacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each search engine has a different set of indexables. If we knew we'd have no SEO industry. Typically they are looking at displayed text, meta data, titles and Alt attributes. Different priority is given to text based upon markup a styling - so a H1 tag would add weighting to its content such that its considered a stronger match.

Crawling a site is not a DoS, unless you make many repeated and unnecessary requests probably from many clients.

Also, the crawl process is exactly as you mention. URLs are submitted by website owners as a starting point. Any links are then crawled - pages are frequently revisited to update to new content. Most sites will include a robots.txt file to tell crawlers what it can look at. It's up to the developer of the crawler to decide if they honour it.